# Simple Steering Behaviour: Explain This Line

Tags: math, artificial-intelligence, physics

I am reading the book Programming Game AI by Example, and he gives code for
a steering behaviour which causes the entity to decelerate so that it arrives
gracefully at a target. After calculating dist, the distance from target to 
source he then (essentially) does this

```
double speed = dist/deceleration;
```

I just cannot understand where this comes from however, am I just missing something
really obvious? It is not listed as a known error in the book so I am guessing it 
is correct.

Comment: This equation doesn't make sense. Would you mind showing us what he actually writes.

Answer (score 2):

If there was some physical truth to this, the units would have match up on either side.

[image: unit comparison]

From what I understand, this is akin to Zeno's paradoxes where you are trying to reach something, but you never get there because you always only travel one `n`th of the remaining distance.

Suppose

- the simulation proceeds at intervals of one second at a time.
- `deceleration` = 5
- `distance` = 1000 meters

With these initial conditions, `speed` will be set to `200` meters per second. Because the simulation proceeds at intervals of one second, we will travel exactly `200` meters (i.e. one fifth of the remaining distance), and end up at a distance of `800` meters from the target. The new speed is determined to be: `160` meters per second

Here is what happens in the first 30 seconds:

[image: formula]
[image: first thirty seconds plot]

The last 30 seconds:
[image: last thirty seconds plot]

The last 10 seconds:
[image: last ten seconds plot]

Observations

- Within the first 30 seconds, we travel roughly 998 meters
- Within the first 50 seconds, we cover 999.985 meters
- Within the last 10 seconds, we cover only ~1.2cm

As you can see, you get almost there very quickly, but it takes a long time to get close.

<sub>Plots by WolframAlpha</sub>

Comment: Game distance is rounded to pixels (integer), therefore if you get in the last 30 seconds under 0.5, you stop.

Comment: @Petr we don't know what the scale is.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is something missing in your calculation. For a constant accelaration (or decelleration), and ignoring initial condictions, the speed is

```
v = a * t
```

and the distance is

```
d = a * t^2 / 2
```

If you eliminate t in both equations you get

```
v = a * sqrt(2 * d / a)
```

Comment: The distance should be half that ;)

Comment: These equations you regurgitate are only valid when starting from `v = 0` and not when *decelerating* i.e. starting from `v = v_0 ≠ 0` as is the case in this question.

Comment: Yeah. That is what 'ignoring initial conditions mean'. But the correction for that is pretty obivous, isn't it?

Comment: For deceleration, it may not be *that* obvious.